# Is there an R package to make shell plots (not fish plots) to depict cancer evolution?

Tags: r, plot, visualization, genetics

I found this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fishplot/versions/0.5  which makes fish plots like this: [image]

but it is difficult to interpret the clone size when the corresponding color is broken into two sections, as the orange and grey clones are here.  Is there an open source package that makes shell plots like this, where it is easier to judge clone size:  (These shell plots were produced with Tapestri, which is proprietary):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you ever found an answer but I have had some success using timescape:
https://github.com/shahcompbio/timescape

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions (such as ones requesting recommendations for offsite resources), as advised in the [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions).